# Java String Method

Tags: java, string

I have comma separated string variable like:

```
String doctors = "doc_vijayan,doc_zubair,doc_Raja"
```

But i want to delete "doc_" from the above String and First Letter should display in capital. I need output like this:

```
String doctors1 = "Vijayan, Zubair, Raja"
```

How to do that?

Comment: How about doing the obvious, reading the documentation of `String`: http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 5):

You can try that :

```
public String splitDoctors(String doctorsString){
    String[] doctors = doctorsString.split(",");
    boolean isFirst = true;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(String doctor : doctors){
        if(!isFirst){
            sb.append(", ");
        }else{
            isFirst = false;
        }
        sb.append(doctor.substring(4,5).toUpperCase());
        sb.append(doctor.substring(5));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: If you use this method, it may be a good idea to use if (doctor.startsWith("doc_")) ... to check if it, in fact, starts with the given string.

Comment: i am facing one issue with above code. first string is displayed twice
like:
String doctors1 = "VijayanVijayan, Zubair, Raja"

Comment: What is the string you use in parameter ?

Answer (score 3):

#### Guava

With [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/), you can write something like this:

```
    import com.google.common.base.*;
    import com.google.common.collect.*;
    //...

    String doctors = "doc_vijayan,doc_zubair,doc_Raja";

    Function<String,String> chopAndCap =
        new Function<String,String>() {
            @Override public String apply(String from) {
                return from.substring(4, 5).toUpperCase()
                    + from.substring(5);
            }           
        };

    Iterable<String> docs = Splitter.on(',').split(doctors);
    docs = Iterables.transform(docs, chopAndCap);
    doctors = Joiner.on(", ").join(docs);

    System.out.println(doctors);
    // Vijayan, Zubair, Raja
```

So the concrete logical steps are:

- Define a [`Function`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html) to perform the chop-and-cap
- Use [`Splitter`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) to split into `Iterable<String>`
- [`Iterables.transform`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#transform%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) each element using the above `Function`
- Use [`Joiner`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) to join from the transformed `Iterable` back to a `String`

If you're comfortable with this kind of programming style, you can just assemble the entire process into one smooth operation:

```
    System.out.println(
        Joiner.on(", ").join(
            Iterables.transform(
                Splitter.on(',').split(doctors),
                new Function<String,String>() {
                    @Override public String apply(String from) {
                        return from.substring(4, 5).toUpperCase()
                            + from.substring(5);
                    }           
                }
            )
        )
    );
    // Vijayan, Zubair, Raja
```

---

#### Apache Commons Lang

With [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/), you can write something like this:

```
    import org.apache.commons.lang.*;
    //...

    String doctors = "doc_vijayan,doc_zubair,doc_Raja";

    String[] docs = StringUtils.split(doctors, ',');
    for (int i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
        docs[i] = StringUtils.capitalize(
            StringUtils.substringAfter(docs[i], "doc_")
        );
    }
    doctors = StringUtils.join(docs, ", ");
    System.out.println(doctors);
    // Vijayan, Zubair, Raja
```

Note that you if you have both Guava and Apache Commons Lang, you can use `StringUtils.capitalize/substringAfter` in `chopAndCap` function above.

Answer (score 1):

```
final String[] docs = doctors.split(",");
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (final String d : docs) {
   String doct = d.replace("doc_", "");
   doct = doct.subString(0,1).toUpperCase() +  doct.subString(1).toLowerCase();
   sb.append(sb.length() > 0 ? ", " : "");
   sb.append(doct);
} // you should be able to do the rest.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String regex = "doc_.";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(doctors);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()) {
    String group = matcher.group();
    int i = group.length() - 1;
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, String.valueOf(group.charAt(i)).toUpperCase());
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);
System.out.print(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use 'any' StringUtils library out there. For example org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils has a chomp and a capitalize method which should bring you a long way.

Comment: can u please elaborate how to use StringUtil for this?

Comment: Sure, i've looked it up, you code make it into a oneliner like this if you use apache commons lang library:
String result = WordUtils.capitalizeFully(StringUtils.chomp(doctors, "doc"), new char[] {','});